# Automatic re-size of a column based on a parameter in Microsoft reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am using Microsoft Report Viewer v11.0.0.0. I have a table with 10 columns in my report page. The last column of the report might be hidden depending on a parameter. What I want is to automatically re-size of a column whose title is Description depending on this parameter (or the visibility of the last column) as well. So lets say if parameter p is 1, then column description would be 5 cm, otherwise it would be 8 cm. I did not see an area for a column to write an IIF expression for its size so got stuck. I would really appreciate if anyone helps.

Edit: I saw this page, but it did not work for me: http://blog.sharepointalist.com/2009/05/ssrs-column-width-auto-size.html

Comment: Would something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262175/dynamic-column-width-for-a-rdlc-report be of help here?

Comment: You can see my comment there in the answer, I saw the page before. It didnt help me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick to accomplish this is to create an extra column that is 8cm wide and contains the same data as the 5cm column.

You have columns A and B.

- A is 5cm
- B is 3cm
- C contains the same data as A but is 8cm

Now select column A and set the column visibility (right-click the column header to edit this).
Set 'show or hide based on expression' to `=IIF(Parameters!Paramter_p.Value = 1, True, False)`

Do the same for B.

Do almost the same for C, but set the 'show or hide based on expression' to `=IIF(Parameters!Paramter_p.Value = 1, False, True)`

Now when `Parameter_p = 1` Column A and B will be visible and take up 8cm.  When `Parameter_p <> 1` Column A and B will not be visible and will be replaced by the 8cm Column C.

This effectively looks like Column A expanded from 5cm to 8cm to take up the extra 3cm space from the hidden Column B.