# In SSRS How to Change the Textbox width Dynamically?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, width

In SSRS How to Change the Textbox width Dynamically? I would like the size to grown to the size of the widest possible value in that given column. (not vertically that I can do, but width).

Comment: Unless something's changed in the past few months, you can't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS tablix column CanGrow property for width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851045/ssrs-tablix-column-cangrow-property-for-width)

Comment: @TabAlleman not exactly a duplicate althought similar. I've working on a text box - individual rather then a table. But it seems that there isn't the ability to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to do this.

Comment: sadly optimistic answer lool